# Import ZenDesk JSON Data to SQL Server using VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, zendesk

I am a complete newby to API's and JSON, however I know what I am doing with SQL and I would say I am an amateur at VB.Net/ASP.Net. We use ZenDesk as our ticketing system, and understand that the link to get the data from it into JSON format is the following url: "https://COMPANYNAME.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json".  I've looked at a lot of 'solutions' on how to get this data into SQL, but none are working for me. I've never used the httpGetWebRequest in VB.Net before, so can please someone explain to me how to go about doing this? I would be very grateful for any assistance people could give me to this - it's doing my nut in!!

Kind Regards,

Miles

Comment: It might help breaking this into bite size pieces - which would also make searching for solutions easier.

1. Get and store the data.  Pull all user data from the Zendesk API - potentially store the JSON locally as raw json or CSV.
2. Set up SQL tables and prepare database. 
3. Process the data.  Write a script to parse the JSON (or CSV) data, open a connection to the DB, and add an entry for each ticket.  

If you can elaborate on what you have tried or how you are stuck, we may be able to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

ZenDesk offers multiple Authentication methods to call their REST APIs.

1. Using basic Authentication (Use userid (e.g. email) and password)
2. Using API Token
3. Using OAuth 2.0

Key thing to understand is passing credentials, parsing JSON response into columns and then looping though multiple responses to extract full data set (REST URL paging)